# How do I return custom HTTP response (400 or 401) from axis 2 web service (REST)?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Is there any way or API to return custom HTTP response from RESTful services using AXIS. All I want is to return custom http response such as 400 or 401 to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If still open... Here is the code about how the get the HTTPServletResponse object and set Status

```
MessageContext responseMessageContext =  
    MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
HttpServletResponse resp =
    (HttpServletResponse) responseMessageContext.getProperty(
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETRESPONSE);
resp.setStatus(422);
```

Hope useful

Answer (score 2):

You can set the response code in the HTTPServletResponse returned form the webservice.

```
response.setStatus(Response.Status.Forbidden)
```

If the webservice doesnot return the Servlet response directly,you need to add this piece of code to the handler which creates the final response before it is wired to the client.

Comment: I want to do it on server side